# How to disable auto received in incoming shipment after user click confirm in Purchase Order in OpenERP v7?

Tags: odoo

Just curious to ask whether why after me create quotation from Purchase Module then click on Confirm Order then when I go to Incoming Shipments in Warehouse, find back my order, how come it already in status "Received"? How to do the setting to allow me manually click on Receive button in Incoming Shipments only it change to the status "Received"? Because when I create a new database then it is work like that but don't know why my current live database will auto help me change to status "Received" in Incoming Shipment after user click on Confirm Order in Purchase Order there? Any suggestion for me to turn it off for auto change the status to Received? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

i work with OpenERP v.7, when i create a quotations from a purchase, and confirm it, and go on warehouse in Incoming Shipements, the Purchase Order in a Ready To Receive State not in Received state, need to do it Menually, i doesn't find direct PO goes in Received State.